# What could I do to make this menu responsive?

Tags: html, css

Hello I been trying to find a way to make this simple menu responsive but when I resize the screen less of 1070px the menu just moves up with the logo and the button and the width doesn't take 100% of the screen, I've tried everything and I can't find the right way, help please!

P.S.
Sorry for my bad english I'm from Japan and still learning the language... 
i'm explain a little more in this picture 1 https://ibb.co/cWJ3sw
i'm explain a little more in this picture 2 https://ibb.co/g7aBeb

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: 'Spectral sc', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: center;}
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #254441;
}
nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #254441;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {display: none;}
nav ul li ul li:hover {background-color: #000;}
nav a:hover {background-color: #000;}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: inherit;}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
}
@media all and (max-width : 1070px) {
  nav {margin: 0;}
  .toggle + a, .menu {display: none;}
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggle:hover {background-color: #000;}
  [id^=drop]:checked + ul {display: block;}
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {padding: 0 40px;}
  nav ul ul ul a {padding: 0 80px;}

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {background-color: #000;}
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {background-color: #212121;}

  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
  nav ul li:hover > ul {display: none;}

  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {position: static;}
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
 <title>Web title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="logo">
  </div>
  <label for="drop" class="toggle" style="float: right;">menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle"">Services +</label>
    <a href="#">Services +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle"">Portfolio +</label>
    <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
     <li>
      <label for="drop-3" class="toggle"">Portfolio +</label>
      <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li> 
      </ul>    
     </li>
    </ul>    
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: simply make the value in the media query smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes you need to make in your media query of 1070px:

- Add this `nav ul{float: left;clear:both;}`

Hope, it helped :)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: 'Spectral sc', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: center;}
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #254441;
}
nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #254441;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.toggle, [id^=drop] {display: none;}
nav ul li ul li:hover {background-color: #000;}
nav a:hover {background-color: #000;}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: inherit;}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
}
@media all and (max-width : 1070px) {
  nav {margin: 0;}
  nav ul{float: left;clear:both;}
  .toggle + a, .menu {display: none;}
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggle:hover {background-color: #000;}
  [id^=drop]:checked + ul {display: block;}
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {padding: 0 40px;}
  nav ul ul ul a {padding: 0 80px;}

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {background-color: #000;}
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {background-color: #212121;}

  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #fff;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
  nav ul li:hover > ul {display: none;}

  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {position: static;}
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
 <title>Web title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="logo">
  </div>
  <label for="drop" class="toggle" style="float: right;">menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle"">Services +</label>
    <a href="#">Services +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle"">Portfolio +</label>
    <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
     <li>
      <label for="drop-3" class="toggle"">Portfolio +</label>
      <a href="#">Portfolio +</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li> 
      </ul>    
     </li>
    </ul>    
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
   
  </ul>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @numero1 No problem :)